# Probability when throwing dice

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, statistics

```
n = 5
k = 3

x = 1
for i in range(1, n + 1):
   x = x * i

y = 1
for i in range(1, k + 1):
   y = y * i

z = 1
for i in range(1, n - k + 1):
   z = z * i

c = x / (y * z)

p = 1
for i in range(k):
   p = p * (1 / 6)

q = 1
for i in range(n - k):
   q = q * (5 / 6)

result = c * p * q
```

So the following code calculates the probability of seeing exactly 3 sixes when throwing 5 dice. However, I'm unsure about the loops in this code.

I'm aware that:

```
n = number of trials
k = number of successes
And p/q success/failure?
```

But what are the loops doing and I'm unsure about the variables x,y,z and c. Traditionally I would just use powers to get the answer for these types of questions but I'm unsure about this method.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like c is the binomial coefficient, used in this probability calculation.
and the loops are used to calculate the required factorials (x is n!, y is k!, and z is (n-k)!).

The loops for p and q are indeed used to calculate the powers of success/fail probabilities.

This code would be much nicer using [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) and [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial)